# Django order of execution

Tags: django

In what order does django execute the various components when it receives a request? Specifically when does the middleware get invoked compared to the function that a route resolves to? And when do context processors get called?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The middlewares are executed before the view and when returning the response.
The context processor is executed when rendering a template, usually at the end of the view.

So:

(request) -> middleware, from top to bottom -> view -> context_processor -> (response) -> middleware, from bottom to top

Comment: @John if this reply answers your question, you should accept it as correct by clicking the green tick on the left!

Comment: Yep - I couldn't for another few hours a while ago

Comment: I don't know exactly: it is surely before the middleware, but I'm not sure whether this happens before or after building the request