# How to use Django Middleware

Tags: django, middleware

I want to know, how to use django middleware, and what they are used for? And what things I can't do without them.

Aren't django's HttpRequest and HttpResponse are enought to handle all sort of things I might need.

Finally, when I should start thinking that I need to go to django's Middleware.

Thanks!

Comment: and...? Try [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=Django%20Middleware) link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: use middlewares if you want something **always** happen **before and/or after each view** (i.e. before the request reaches your views or after response has left them).

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185493/django-order-of-execution/6185594#6185594).

Use them if you want to do something that is not view-specific before or after all your views.
E.g. if you want to log all the requested urls, you should use a middleware that gets request.path and writes it somewhere.

Comment: First of all, Thanks Don for your answer, secondly, Can't I do that simply with HttpResponse/Request in my application? The point is, most of the time I won't think about middleware, at which point shall I start thinking about them..am I missing something

Comment: Thanks all guys for help and support

Answer (score 5):

Django middleware are a framework feature that helps you to do a same set of actions for *all* of your requests. You can think of it as a light, low-level “plugin” system for globally altering Django’s input and/or output. You can define any numbers of middlewares, and then can enable any subset of them using the `MIDDLEWARES` tuple in `settings.py`.

More precisely, a middleware is a class that has a few functions: process_request, process_view, process_template_response, etc. and django will call each of its functions for each process in a certain time, for example process_view is called before your code in views.py is executed.

Consequently, if you want to do a same thing for all of your requests, you can think of middlewares as a flexible and powerfull option. To learn more about middlewares and how to write them, see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/